# CSS not styling the DIV correctly when styled text is entered

Tags: css, html, text-styling

I'm trying to format text that is in a DIV, however, I also want to style the DIV.

In the PHP page I have the DIV and the text:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <h1>Welcome to the Drug Debate!</h1>
    <p>Home of facts and deabtes of legal and illegal drugs!The Drug debate offers a safe and relaxed enviroment where you will be able to find information and facts about different types of drug </p>
</div>
```

Then in my CSS I am trying to style that DIV using:

```
#main-content{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width:600px;
height: 350px;
margin: 0 auto;
border:solid;
}
```

and the `<h1>` and `<p>` using:

```
h1 {
 font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:24px;
 padding-left:200px;

}
```

(and similar for `<p>`)

This is creating problems, such as the background colour for the DIV isn't applying behind the text?

(please bear in mind i'm quite new to coding and this site!!)

Comment: `#FFF` or `#FFFFFF` means white! change color See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RRH7G/1/)

Comment: It's probably cause you're applying a white background to your `h1` and to your `div`.  #FFFFFF is the colour value for white, you can discover hex colours here http://www.colorpicker.com/

Comment: White on white, beauty. Like that's gonna show.

Comment: it isn't white on white, beauty. i have styled my site background to be grey, so it does show.

Comment: well that's what you had for code, originally. @user3169325 since you [**edited it a minute ago**](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20976414/1). So there.

Comment: Your site background isnt grey its white becoz background-color: #FFFFFF; means white

Comment: * {

margin: 0;

padding: 0;

border: 0;

background-color:#848484;

}

this is also in the CSS

Comment: @user3169325 when you call #main-content{ background-color: #FFFFFF } it means it basically overwrites the first css and creates and displays in white , do you want this - http://jsfiddle.net/tbwy7/

Comment: Gray is `#c0c0c0` `#999999` or `#666666` etc. I know these by heart. This question needs to be closed, shows no effort to solve. It's CSS, not `C++` what's so hard about that? `$that="CSS";`

Comment: Try applying your colour to the body tag? `body { background-color: #848484; }`

Comment: @user3169325 You need to Learn the Basics , better practice at http://codeacademy.com , Try the webfundamentals course,it really is worth for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [default background color property is transparent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color), which is why you see the background color from your universal selector coming through. Simply add `background-color:inherit;` to your CSS.

```
h1, p {
    font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-left:200px;
    background-color:inherit;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Ph632/1/)**